# Serialize class with abstract parameter to JSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, moshi

I have 3 classes:

1. `GameResultList` which is basically ArrayList with some helper methods in it
2. `GameResult` with an abstract value `gameMode`
3. `GameMode`

```
public class GameResultList extends ArrayList<GameResult> {
    ...
}
```

```
class GameResult(
    val gameMode: GameMode,
    val score: Int,
    timeSpentInSeconds: Int,
    val completionDateTime: Date
) {
    ...
}
```

GameMode class:

```
abstract class GameMode(
    val suggestionsActivated: Boolean,
    val screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation // enum: PORTRAIT, HORIZONTAL
) {
    ...
}
```

I need to serialize `GameResultList` into JSON.

Since the parameter `gameMode` is abstract, Gson throws an exception. After some research, I decided to give Moshi a try. I have added `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` and `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory`, but the result is always empty (`{}`).

How I set up Moshi:

```
    private val moshi =
        Moshi.Builder().add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(GameMode::class.java, "GameMode")
            .withSubtype(GameOnTime::class.java, "GameOnTime")
            .withSubtype(GameOnCount::class.java, "GameOnCount"))
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    private val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<GameResultList> = moshi.adapter(GameResultList::class.java)
```

This returns empty JSON response:
`jsonAdapter.toJson(gameResultList)`

So how can I serialize the `GameResultList`? Is there an easy way? Also, it's not necessary to use Moshi, it can be anything else for the sake of easiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found out that the main problem is that array lists require explicit converters.

```
class GameResultListToJsonAdapter {

    @ToJson
    fun arrayListToJson(list: GameResultList): List<GameResult> = list

    @FromJson
    fun arrayListFromJson(list: List<GameResult>): GameResultList = GameResultList(list)

}
```

Also, there is a problem with handling the `Date` type, I have replaced it with `Long` to not make another explicit converter.